# Formatting page numbering

Tags: fancyhdr, lastpage

I am trying to have the page numbering in my homework file as a fraction. However, when I try to display the fraction in a different colour, the last page does not change its colour. How do I ensure that the whole fraction is green, and not just the current page?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{myGreen}{rgb}{0,.4,0}

\fancyfoot[R]{\textcolor{myGreen}{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, your code doesn't produce the output you show.

Answer (score 4):

You probably use coloured links and the colour of the link to the last page interferes with the colour you chose for your page numbers. You can disable the link color like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\fancyfoot[R]{\textcolor{green}{\hypersetup{hidelinks}\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @grumpyeconomist You're welcome! In the future please make sure that the code in your question actually reproduces the problem!

Answer (score 4):

The code posted doesn't produce a fractional page number at all because the custom footer is never applied. When I adapt the code to apply the footer, I get a uniformly coloured fraction.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{myGreen}{rgb}{0,.4,0}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textcolor{myGreen}{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

[image: green numerator and denominator in fractional page number]

Note that you may not actually need `lastpage` for this functionality. However, the documentation currently seems a little confused, so I would keep using `lastpage` if it does the job for now. (The documentation says equivalent functionality is available in the kernel, but that more advanced uses may require `pageslts`. Then it says `pageslts` is incompatible with current LaTeX.)